# Floating Point Number with 2 Digits of Precision SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g and was wondering how to set the precision of a floating point number (price column) to 2 digits of precision:

I tried:

```
Create Table MealItem (
        itemId varchar(10) Primary Key,
        name varchar(30),
        price float(2),
        calories int Check(calories <= 500)
);
```

This didn't give the correct output in the table. If I enter `20.99` as the price it rounds it off to 21. Although I would like the maintain the decimal to 2 digits of precision (So I would like 20.99 instead of 21).

Comment: Which Database engine you are using

Comment: I think I am using Oracle DB11G

Comment: do you want to store 20 when you enter 20.99

Comment: use `decimal(10,2)`. Also don't use `Float` it is a approximate datatype

Comment: Oh ok. Also the above query I wrote is incorrect, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does `Decimal(10,2)` worked?.  This will have maximum of 2 decimal points

Comment: Oh no that is correct. The query I wrote before with the Round.

Comment: Ok! Will keep that in mind.